# How can I make an object callable?

Tags: ruby

Is there a way to create a object that has properties and can be called using only the notation of a function call? Something equivalent to Python's `__call__`.

For example:

```
obj = ExampleClass.new()
obj() # call notation
```

Alternate approaches are welcome, I need a way for the callable "object" to store its own properties.

What I am trying to do is store a callable "object" in a variable. This object has properties that are associated with it, while at the same time, it can be used exactly like a method.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of (nor can I think of a great use case to do so). What specific usecase are you trying to resolve? There may be a better approach.

Comment: "it can be used exactly like a function" - note that ruby doesn't have functions (the kind you have in, say, javascript)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're willing to change the desired syntax a little bit...

```
class Foo
  def call
    puts 'called'
  end
end

f = Foo.new
f.()
# >> called
```

The exact syntax, as in your question, is not possible in ruby, because parentheses are optional and, therefore, `f()` is the same as `f`. Which, in the case of a callable object is ambiguous. Do you want to perform the call or only reference the callable object? Explicit call (with the dot syntax) removes the ambiguity.

Answer (score 6):

You can't make an object callable, as far as I know that's reserved for method calls, but you can do it with a bit of a hack using an alternate notation:

```
class ExampleClass
  def []
    :callable
  end
end
```

Where now you can do:

```
example = ExampleClass.new
example[]
```

This is similar to how you can call a Proc:

```
proc = Proc.new { :return_value }
proc[]
# => :return_value
```

It's not perfect, but it'll work.

Note that normally you can side-step a lot of this mess by architecting your API around these limitations.

Answer (score -2):

One thing that u can do is simple create an class and a function with the same name:

class Thing
end

def Thing()
end

Thing.new
Thing()